# Opening multiple jQueryUI dialogs

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery

I wish to open multiple jQuery dialogs, one after the other. But only the first one opens.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rKPPQ/)

Dlg 1 -- Presents a YES / NO question.

Dlg 2 -- If YES, stick the word "go" into the hidden field `id="frmtrig"` and then trigger a change event. When this event is caught, it runs AJAX to populate the $('#message') div with html received via ajax success function, and then displays that in a dialog.

Dlg 3 -- After closing, present one final dialog.

Below code breaks at step 2. The `alert('bonk')` doesn't even happen...

**I also deleted everything between `alert('bonk')` and the closing `}` of the success function, and the bonk alert still does not display. Can anyone spot a problem with my AJAX code?**

Oddly, I've done a ton of (relatively simple) AJAX, so I'm puzzled that I'm getting stuck here.  **Note that it might be necessary to copy/paste my code blocks into two or 3 files on your own server to test this out, since jsFiddle won't work for troubleshooting AJAX.**

I have been unsuccessful finding an example of doing this, and my own efforts over the past two days have not worked.

HTML

```
    <div id="hot_link">Hover over this line to begin it all</div>
    <div id="message"></div>
    <div id="alert"></div>
    <input type="hidden" id="frmtrig">
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
$(function(){

    var cnt = 0;
    var ans = 0;
    var seen = 0;
    var dlg = $('#message');

    dlg.dialog({
        title: '"The Big Test',
        autoOpen:false,
        modal:true,
        width: 500,
        close: function() {
            if (seen==0 && ans > 0) {
                cnt++;
                seen++;
                dlg.dialog('open');
            }
        }
    });

    $('#hot_link').hover(
        function() {
            //Hover-in
            if (cnt < 1 || (cnt % 3 == 0)) {
                var msg = '<p>If you say NO, the Dialog will just close. If you press YES, an AJAX call will happen.</p>';
                dlg.html(msg);
                dlg.dialog(
                    'option',
                    'buttons',
                        [{
                            text: 'Download',
                            click: function() {
                                ans++;
                                //seen = 5;
                                $('#frmtrig').val('go').change();
                                $(this).dialog('close');
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            text: 'Not now',
                            click: function() {
                                ans = 0;
                                $(this).dialog('close');
                            }
                        }]
                );
                dlg.dialog('open');
                //alert('hi');
            }
            cnt++;
        },
        function() {
            //Hover-out
            //need this one to prevent duplicating hover-in code
        }
    );

    $('#frmtrig').change(function() {
    alert('boink');
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                async: false,
                url: "ajax/ax_all_ajax_fns.php",
                data: 'request=freegive_99',
                success:function(data){
alert('bonk');
alert(data);
                    var dlg = $('#message');
alert('me be here');
                    dlg.html(data);
                    dlg.dialog(
                        'option',
                        'buttons',
                            [{
                                text: 'OK',
                                click: function() {
                                    $(this).dialog('close');
                                }
                            }]
                    );
                    dlg.dialog('open');
                }
            });
    });

}); //END document.ready
```

---

AX_ALL_AJAX_FNS.PHP

```
    if ($_POST['request'] == 'freegive_99') {
        echo 'THIS_LINE_WORKS';
    }
```

Comment: Post it on jsfiddle. There's no way to fix it looking at it like this.

Comment: That change event on the hidden field is wrong. That's not how change() works. Please post somewhere, I'll help you.

Comment: What final dialog do you want to display?

Comment: It's on jSFiddle now (Posting link above)

Comment: @HighKickX I didn't include the final dlg but I had intended to re-populate the `#message` DIV and call another jQ UI Dlg.  Not sure how or where to call it, though ! (Even if the final Dlg says "This is the final dialog", I'll be happy)

Comment: Your code on jsFiddle won't work because the ajax request points to a resource that can't be loaded (`ajax/ax_all_ajax_fns.php` not found).

Comment: Actually, that's not why it doesn't work. I've done quite a bit of AJAX so I'm not new at it, but jsFiddle doesn't handle AJAX so that's why it doesn't work at that point.

Comment: @gibberish I have tested your code on local and it works fine, make sure the file `ajax/ax_all_ajax_fns.php` is where you think it is. The success function is not called, that's why you don't have the other dialogs to open.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31552/discussion-between-highkickx-and-gibberish)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried your code on my machine and it is working fine.

If the second dialog is not opened, it means that `success` in your `ajax` request is not reached.

Are you sure that the problem doesn't come from a wrong path?

```
url: "ajax/ax_all_ajax_fns.php", // Check this path
```

Comment: You solved it. I knew the path was correct (and it is) so I was flabbergasted to find that it's a 404 problem UNLESS I add some junk HTML to the top of the file (which breaks the AJAX, of course).  But at least I know what my true problem is now.  Thanks again.